# going to for a non planned decision

Tags: future-tense, will-vs-going-to

> After Harry had given the lecture, while he was descending from the
>   podium, however, one of the research assistants intercepted him, and 
>   began to ask him a question on the theory of relativity.... one that
>   involved a lot of complex calculations and equations. Harry  replied
>   to the assistant “The answer to this question is very simple! In fact,
>   it’s so simple, that I **am going to** let my chauffeur answer it!”

Why is it not **will let** as the decision was taken when he was replying, he did not make any plan before answering?

Is **going to** used to say that the chauffeur is going to answer right now?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, "to be going to" expresses more like intent, rather than detailed plan.

Even so, "to be going to" is still suitable, because a plan is still a plan, regardless of when it was conceived: just now while speaking, or during the last 2 weeks.

"Will let" would work in this situation very well too.